# Matplotlib: Search for user specified font and implement in plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I would like to use a user specified font to do plots through a script i'm writing. I would like to have cross-platform compatibility. 
I am trying something like this:

```
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

user_specified_font = 'Computer Modern Roman'  

sysfonts = fm.findSystemFonts(fontpaths=None)
fnames = [fm.FontProperties(fname=fname).get_name() for fname in sysfonts] 

if user_specified_font in fnames:
    plt.rcParams['font.family']=user_specified_font
else:
    plt.rcParams['font.family']='Times New Roman'
```

But, this does not work and nothing changes in the plots. I am making some mistake somewhere. Any help will be great!!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. The code above runs fine. Have you made sure that `'Computer Modern Roman' ` is actually in sysfonts?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thanks for trying it out. You are right, the above code now runs fine. I had put somewhere 'rc('text', usetex=True)' which i guess created the problem. So when 'usetex=False' al works great!